# Problem in Building Project in Asp.net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm facing a problem of building a project of ASP.NET core 2.2 in visual studio 2017. Please Note that I'm successfully able to build and run project in ASP.NET core 2.1 . I have installed asp.net core 2.2 . I have also found in visual studio that when I created a Project of ASP.NET core I select .NET core version 2.2 As shown in the picture  . [image]

When I build the project first time I got this error

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2. WebApplication2 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.505\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   137 "

Please note that I have installed .net core 2.2 through package manager console through nuget but still I'm getting this yellow sign suggest that dependency problem . Please see the picture  in bellow .[image]

So I could not able to build and run the project what should I do . Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you tell me your installed .NET Core 2.2 SDK version?

Comment: yes I have 2 vesion of .NET core  and those are 2.1.9 and 2.2.4

Comment: These are not SDK version. These are Framework version. SDK versions are like `SDK 2.2.203`

Comment: yes found 2.2.203 after I dotnet --version command  in cmd

Comment: Okay! 2.2.203 is for Visual Studio 2019! For Visual Studio 2017, Its `SDK 2.2.106`. Please download it from here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 and install and then let me know!

Comment: Thanks I'm seeing it is working or not thanks

Comment: Okay! Keep me updated! 

Comment: Another thing- don't forget to update your Visual Studio 2017 to its latest version!

Comment: Thanks It works Brother . Many Many thanks.

Comment: Its great to hear that! I have posted it as answer. Please green check and upvote this. Happy Coding! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems you have installed the wrong the version of **.NET Core SDK** for .NET Core 2.2.4 and Visual Studio 2017. You said that you have downloaded and installed the .NET Core SDK version `2.2.203` which is actually for Visual Studio 2019! That's the problem!

For Visual Studio 2017, Its `SDK 2.2.106` for .NET Core 2.2.4. Please download it from here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 and install.

You error should go away now!

Answer (score 0):

Download the SDK 2.2 in dot net core I think you don't have the SDK downloaded for the targeted version.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2